# Read perticular value in XML file in javascript & return all values in same row

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I found a answer of above question in stackoverflow but that is stopped working since yesturday please help me.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Do you need to read by specific tag,element or child ?

Comment: What have you already tried?  What is the code which is not working?

Comment: I am trying to create one html page which can do something similar below:
xml file data.xml:
<root>
    <row>
        <name>Name</name>
        <id>1</id>
    </row>
</root>

js file:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#find').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXML
        });
    });
});


adding function in below comment.

Comment: function parseXML(xml){
 var searchFor = $('#search').val();
        var reg = new RegExp(searchFor, "i");
 $(xml).find('row').each(function(){
  var n = $(this).find('name').text();
                var nSearch = n.search(reg);
  var i = $(this).find('id').text();
               if(nSearch > -1){
                $('#output').append('search name's ID is:'+i.replace(reg,searchFor)');
                 }
             });
}


Note: I have added <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
Above code was working till yesturday and suddenly stopped working.